# jsonDecode() not getting UTF8 chars properly

Tags: json, dart

so I'm getting fortnite usernames through an api. For example, instead of giving me COCA lightツ., it gives COCA lightã��.

If I hard code any of these special chars (flutter web), it works. And the raw response from the api gives me the good name.
Here's my method:

```
static dynamic getNameFromId(String id) async {
    final response = await http.get('https://fortniteapi.io/stats?account=$id', headers: {
      'Authorization': FortniteAPI.auth,
    });
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return jsonDecode(response.body)['name'];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: try this :     return jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes))['name'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API does not contain any charset in its response header so the `http` library cannot automatically determine the charset. In the documentation for `body` you can find this:

> This is converted from bodyBytes using the charset parameter of the Content-Type header field, if available. If it's unavailable or if the encoding name is unknown, latin1 is used by default, as per RFC 2616.

https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Response/body.html

You can fix the problem by doing the UTF8 parsing manually with:

```
return jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes))['name'];
```